# Nesting custom `xparse` environments

Tags: environments, nesting, xparse

I've defined two simple environments with `xparse`. Problem is when I try to nest `todominute` environment inside `minutes` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {minutes} {} {%
    \begin{table*}[h!]
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} p{0.25\textwidth} l p{0.4\textwidth} l @{}}
        \textbf{Zadanie} & \textbf{Typ} & \textbf{Opis} & \textbf{Przydział} \\
        \midrule
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{table*}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {todominute} {m O{}} {%
    {#1} & \textsc{TODO} &
}{%
    & {#2} \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minutes}
    \begin{todominute}{Poprawki opisu produktu}[TC]
        Zgodnie z opisem z paragrafu \ref{sec:opis_produktu}.
    \end{todominute}
    \begin{todominute}{Poprawki mapy pamięci}[MM]
        Zgodnie z opisem z paragrafu \ref{sec:mapa_pamieci}.
    \end{todominute}
\end{minutes}

\end{document}
```

All I get is somewhat unhelpful message:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endpbox ...finalstrut \@arstrutbox \par \egroup 
                                                  \hfil 
l.27 ...n{todominute}{Poprawki opisu produktu}[TC]
```

**EDIT:**
After the reading the comments I understand the problem. Is there a simple way to achieve the desired behaviour? Can I declare a new command that could be used like that and as a result print whole rows for the table declared in `minutes` environment?

```
\begin{minutes}
    \todominute{Poprawki opisu produktu}[TC]
        Zgodnie z opisem z paragrafu \ref{sec:opis_produktu}.
    \todominute{Poprawki mapy pamięci}[MM]
        Zgodnie z opisem z paragrafu \ref{sec:mapa_pamieci}.
\end{minutes}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that should compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do. It's hard having to guess at all the necessary packages.

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be in the fact that you open the environment in a table cell and close it in another: this is not allowed, because environments form a group.

Comment: you would get a similar error without all the packages if you went `\begin{tabular}{cc}  \begingroup a & b \endgroup \\ `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem goes away if you use a command rather than an environment for the table row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {minutes} {} {%
    \begin{table*}[htp!]
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} p{0.25\textwidth} l p{0.5\textwidth} l @{}}
        \textbf{Zadanie} & \textbf{Typ} & \textbf{Opis} & \textbf{Przydział} \\
        \midrule
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{table*}
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\todominute} {m o m} {
    #1 & \textsc{TODO} & #3
    & #2 \tabularnewline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minutes}
    \todominute{Poprawki opisu produktu}[TC]
        {Zgodnie z opisem z paragrafu \ref{sec:opis_produktu}.}
    \todominute{Poprawki mapy pamięci}[MM]
        {Zgodnie z opisem z paragrafu \ref{sec:mapa_pamieci}.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item asd
            \item qwe
            \item zxc
        \end{enumerate}
    }
\end{minutes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After going through `xparse` documentation I've got little question. Shouldn't in this case the command declaration use the `+` token for the last argument, as in `\NewDocumentCommand {\todominute} {m o +m} { ... }`?

Comment: @tomasz  er yes to make it long (allow blank lines) that would probably be better

Answer (score 1):

I've modified a bit the solution presented by David.

I wanted to avoid wrapping the usually long text that goes in the *Details* column in curly brackets.

My method isn't really flexible, when it comes to the order of arguments, as only the last column can be filled without putting its content in an `{}`-wrapped argument.

Anyway, using it this way feels way more natural, as it resembles the default `itemize` environment. As a bonus it doesn't mess up the syntax colouring in your text editor.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {minutes} { } {%
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth} @{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Minute} & \textbf{Owner} & \textbf{Details} \tabularnewline
        \midrule
}{%
        \end{minipage} \tabularnewline
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\minute} { s m O{} } {%
    \IfBooleanTF #1 {%
    }{%
        \end{minipage} \tabularnewline
        \midrule
    }%
    {#2} & {#3} &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
}


\begin{document}


\begin{minutes}
    \minute*{Subject 1}%
        The first item \textbf{has to be} starred:\newline
        \verb=\minute*{The first...}=
    \minute{Info 2}
        The rest \textbf{musn't} be starred.
    \minute{Task 2}[TC]%
        So it goes.
\end{minutes}


\end{document}
```