# Using tabu/tabularx inside xparse NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: environments, tabularx, tabu, xparse

My question seems very similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83420/nesting-custom-xparse-environments), but with `tabu` instead of `tabular*`. In fact, switching the options in that example causes the failure I see here.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment {trace} {} {%
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|@{ }r@{::}l|l|X|}
    A & B & C & D \\
}{%
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
}

\begin{trace}
 a & b & c & d \\
\end{trace}
```

This fails with `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \tabu@0.H4
l.51 \end{trace}`. Similarly for the tabularx environment, which also allows X. The below works just fine, but doesn't allow the X parameter I would like to use

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment {trace} {} {%
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|@{ }r@{::}l|l|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
    A & B & C & D \\
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command-form within the environment definition in order to successfully compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tabu,tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xparse,tabu,tabularx}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {traceA} {} {%
  \table
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{|@{ }r@{::}l|l|X|}
    A & B & C & D \\
  }{%
    \endtabularx
  \endtable
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {traceB} {} {%
  \table
    \tabu to \linewidth {|@{ }r@{::}l|l|X|}
      A & B & C & D \\
  }{%
    \endtabu
  \endtable
}

\begin{document}
\begin{traceA}
 a & b & c & d
\end{traceA}

\begin{traceB}
 a & b & c & d
\end{traceB}
\end{document}
```

The [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf) (section **5 The Macros**, p 4) eludes to this somewhat:

> Now a trick to get the body of an environment into a token register, without
>   doing any expansion. This does not do any real checking of nested environments,
>   so if you should need to nest one `tabularx` inside another, the inner one must be
>   surrounded by `{ }`.
>
> [...]
>
> This mechanism of grabbing an environment body does have the disadvantage
>   (shared with the AMS alignment environments) that you can not make extension
>   environments by code such as
>
> ```
> \newenvironment{foo}{\begin{tabularx}{XX}}{\end{tabularx}}
> ```
>
> as the code is looking for a literal string `\end{tabularx}` to stop scanning. Since
>   version 2.02, one may avoid this problem by using `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx`
>   directly in the definition:
>
> ```
> \newenvironment{foo}{\tabularx{XX}}{\endtabularx}
> ```
>
> The scanner now looks for the end of the current environment (`foo` in this example.) There are some restrictions on this usage, the principal one being that
>   `\endtabularx` is the first token of the "end code" of the environment.

My guess is [`tabu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) relies on similar restrictions.

Comment: Great! Can I ask a quick followup: Now `\NewDocumentCommand \tline { m m m m } {%
    #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \}` and `\begin{trace}
 \tline{a}{b}{c}{d}
\end{trace}` fails with the same error Missing number

Comment: @Hamy: This works fine for `tabularx`, but not `tabu`. `tabu` doesn't like an empty line break at the end. Try `\NewDocumentCommand \tline { m m m m } {% #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 }`